# SSL Certificate warning in Firefox

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I bought a ssl certificate generated with SHA-2 algorithm.
It was successfully installed in apache2 server. I also test it with online tool like https://www.sslshopper.com and the result is completely ok, however in firefox console I got something like this

> This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1.

I also double checked with Chrome and other browser. It seems ok.

is there any gotchas related to my certificate ?

please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Check with a tool like SSL Labs (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html). Does it show multiple trust paths, one of which happens to use SHA1 certs?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: @AnandBhat here is the result https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=bookmebus.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your certificate is fine. The warnings logged in the Firefox console are due to resources served from other domains (speficially, [s-static.ak.facebook.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=s-static.ak.facebook.com&latest), [connect.facebook.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=connect.facebook.com&latest)and [avocado-app.s3.amazonaws.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=avocado-app.s3.amazonaws.com&latest)) that use SHA-1 certificates.

[image: Warnings related to SHA-1 certificate in Firefox console]

Comment: thanks alot. I should have seen this if i had used builtin inspector instead of firebug.